# PHP: call to a REST api

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication

I am trying to call a vChargeBack API for getting information on vCenter server. I am having issues with this.

I have to pass request as XML data in request body. And also I have to pass version as URL parameter. The code I have written is

```
$xmlfile=simplexml_load_file('login.xml');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xmlfile);//Passing XML file as POST field
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://xx.xx.xx.xx/vCenter-CB/api/login");//Setting URL  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false );//Since I am requesting https
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , false );//Since I am requesting https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: ' . $this->acceptType ));
$response=curl_exec($ch);//Getting response
$responseInfo=curl_getinfo($ch);//Getting response headers
```

When I execute, I have 400 Bad Request response. What I noticed is I am not sending version as URL parameter.
It should be 
Name : version
value : 1.5.0
I am not knowing how to send this version as URL parameter. Should I send that as POSTFIELD then how should i send xml file as a request body.

Please help me...

Regards,
Srinath

Comment: Do they not give you an example? "URL parameter" sounds like you should be doing `https://xx.xx.xx.xx/vCenter-CB/api/login?version=1.5.0`

Comment: They didn't give example in PHP but i have example in java, they created an object for PostMethod class and set the version using `NameValuePair[] parameters = {new NameValuePair("version","1.5.0")}; post = new PostMethod(uri); post.setQueryString(parameters);` I have tried `https://xx.xx.xx.xx/vCenter-CB/api/login?version=1.5.0` also, it is still saying Bad Request.

Comment: That's useful. The query string is the part that comes after the ? in a url, not the body of the POST. So you're on the right track, but I don't know what else you're doing wrong as I have no idea what this API is and won't be reading its documentation.

Comment: I am still not able to say where I am going wrong.. Some one please help me

Comment: The reason you have no answers is that you have not provided enough information to help you, and even if you did by providing the API specification for the request you're trying to make, you're unlikely to get someone to read it and implement it for you for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chargeback interface is not RESTful. It's an XML portal with resources at given endpoints defined by the documentation. To log in, fill in the `API_NAMESPACE` as the XML namespace provided for your installation, `API_VERSION` as the API version number, `TYPE` (which can be "local" or "ldap"). `NAME` and `PASSWORD` should be obvious.

```
<Request xmlns="$API_NAMESPACE/$API_VERSION">
    <Users>
        <User>
            <Type>$TYPE</Type>
            <Name>$NAME</Name>
            <Password>$PASSWORD</Password>
        </User>
    </Users>
</Request>
```

Generate a POST request to `https://hostname/vCenter-CB/api/login?version=$API_VERSION` with the raw POST-data set to the XML above. Remember to keep the session cookie you are sent after this request returns, as it represents your session to the server.

Also, if you're using LDAP logins, you may have to include an `LdapUsers` child element below the `Users` (as a sibling of the `User` element) to provide LDAP credentials. This is documented in the API Programming Guide from VMware.